# Movie about earth being frozen, protagonist saves the day with sattelite

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I think I saw the second half of this movie a couple of years ago (2010 or earlier) when it aired on TV on a Belgian channel. The movie was in color and couldn't have been that old.

### What I think happened in the first part

- Because of something the earth is covered in dense clouds, the sun can't reach the surface any more and so the whole planet is frozen.
- The male protagonist joins/is forced to join (?) the military and has to leave his wife and daughter behind in his village.
- He meets the secondary main character, a woman.

### Scenes I remember very clearly (not sure about the order)

- His unit gets back to the original village, he runs into his house and finds his wife and daughter laying in bed together, both died of the cold a while ago. He finds a letter from his wife saying "It's getting colder and colder, we stay close together to preserve the little heat out bodies still produce". The woman says "Aren't you happy you joined the military after all?" He replies: "No, I would much rather have stayed with my family".
- They save the day by going into some kind of control tower and enabling a satellite (?) that transmits the solar rays trough the clouds onto the earths surface, you can clearly see them on-screen.

### Extra info

- The movie was set in the present/near-future, there wasn't any tech that doesn't exist today, except for the solar-beaming satellite.
- The soldiers were wearing the typical white/grey uniforms you see in snowy areas, and were equipped with assault rifles with the same patttern.
- The movie was in English

I'm not sure if there was an antagonist or what actually caused the global frost.

Comment: Parts of this are remindig me of The Day After Tomorrow, but it's probably something more less known?

Comment: @DarthLocke I skimmed the plot on Wikipedia a bit, but unfortunately it looks like there's too much stuff missing, like the protagonist actually solving the issue or finding his family. I also don't think the president played a role in the film I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Post Impact (2004)**

[image: poster]

> In 2010, during a party at the US embassy in Berlin, Germany,
>   scientist Gregor Starndorf is told that the comet he discovered,
>   designated Bay-Leder 7, is headed towards Earth. It is large enough to
>   cause an extinction level event and is only days away. **He develops a
>   satellite weapon called SolStar-2**, which is moderately successful
>   against the comet: the microwave beam cut Bay-Leder 7 in two, but the
>   smaller part impacts in western Russia. The head of US embassy
>   security, Captain Tom Parker picks up his family so they can be
>   evacuated. However, his superior, Colonel Waters, forces Parker to
>   leave them behind, watching helplessly as the aircraft takes off. News
>   reports depict the after effects of the impact.
>
> Three years later, the situation has not improved. Due to the debris
>   thrown into the atmosphere, all of Europe's population was evacuated
>   to Africa, where a new ruling body, the New United Northern States
>   (NUNS), has been established. Oil prices also skyrocketed, enabling
>   the Middle East to establish a firm grip on the world economy. A NUNS
>   technician finds that SolStar-2 is still active. **But the satellite can
>   only be controlled from the command center below the Reichstag. The
>   problem is, since the comet impact, Germany is covered in huge layers
>   of ice.** An aircraft, carrying personnel sent to investigate, explodes
>   while flying over the area. Evidence points to SolStar-2 in the
>   attack. NUNS President Miranda Harrison recruits Parker to lead an
>   expedition—including ex-SAS Sarah Henley and Anna Starndorf, Gregor
>   Starndorf's daughter, to find out who controls the satellite and
>   destroy it. Although Parker knows the mission is led by Colonel
>   Waters, he asks to join, secretly hoping that his family is somehow
>   alive...
>
> Parker and **Anna continue the search for his family and find his home.
>   Inside he discovers his wife's final message to him beside their
>   frozen bodies.** Back outside, they watch the thick, permanent clouds
>   over Germany dissipate, **revealing the warming sun once again**.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Impact

**Trailer:**

Answer (score 1):

The parts about the sun not reaching the surface, the whole planet frozen, and saving the day with a control tower and satellite, all sound like [The Colony](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1160996/) with Lawrence Fishburn.

Although The Colony is from 2013 and the main character doesn't have a wife or daughter.

Comment: While that is an awfully close match, I don't think the film was this ... bloody. Also the sattelite is specifically used to transmit the heat of the sun to the surface, not to find a suitable locations. Nice find though!